# Partition keeps filling up, don't know why

Tags: ubuntu, partition, hard-drive

My partition /dev/sda1 keeps filling up. Besides the "/" directory, I cannot tell what directories are even on this partition in order to search for files to delete. I was able to get it down to 97% full yesterday, but already today it is as 100% again.

I did not set up this machine.  But looks like /home is on /dev/sda6 (which has tons of space) so no problems there.

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              9611492   9059720     63532 100% /
tmpfs                 12368424         0  12368424   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                  12363580       172  12363408   1% /dev
tmpfs                 12368424         0  12368424   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda6            452427328 146862508 282582832  35% /home
tmpfs                  2048000   1212456    835544  60% /mnt/ramdisk
```

EDIT:  Still don't know why /dev/sda1 is filling up, but I"m now trying to delete unnecessary packages to free up disk space.  However, it won't let me do anything with an apt-get command.  It says:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vim : Depends: vim-runtime (= 2:7.2.445+hg~cb94c42c0e1a-1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

This occurs also when I try install something.

EDIT 2:  While rebooted got me down to 46% full, now just two days later I am back up to 62% full, and rising. What is filling up my disk?

EDIT 3:  Looks like it's going up about 6% per day...already 68% full. That's about 60 mb/day.

EDIT 4: Looks like I am going up 0.03 MB/HR constantly.  How can I tell what is filling and where?

Comment: Check /var/log directory

Comment: Thanks, I did, but only free'd a little.

Answer (score 5):

This command will give you a list of what is using your disk space, in largest to smallest order, without traversing onto other filesystems (so just / and anything sda1)

```
du -xkc / | sort -r -n | tee /home/diskusage.log
less /home/diskusage.log
```

It will take a while to run, but hopefully that gives you a better idea of what folders are using your disk space. The command dumps the output file to /home since you said it was on a different partition. The results are in KB.

Update:
From what you're saying, the used diskspace doesn't equal the partition size; you might want to check for deleted files to see if there is anything big being held open. Deleted files won't be freed until they are closed. Use lsof to check for deleted files:

```
lsof -n | grep -i '(deleted)'
```

To free such files, close or restart the process that is holding those deleted files open.

Comment: Thank you. I ran it, and the "total" of / is 4100692, which doesn't seem very large. /usr tops the list with 3283184.  The partition is 10 gb, and just filled up 300 mb since last night. 

Any way to get a list files or dir on /dev/sda1 ? Looks like / is not the only location.

Comment: the -k option means 1K blocks. Still 4.1GB is too small. If you didn't run it as root, you might have had some permission denied stuff that might explain the difference too.

Comment: I am root.   Shows /dev/sda1 size 9611492 used 9051400.  BTW, how do I paste code and get it formatted in the gray box?

Comment: Add your output from df -k to your question.

Comment: prefix lines with 4 spaces to make it show as a code block. Run the lsof -n command looking for deleted files. The filesize in bytes is in column 8

Comment: I appreciate your help. I posted the df output above. Forgive me, but why am I looking for deleted files? Do they take up space?

Comment: Yes, they take up space until the process holding them open closes the files.

Comment: lsof output (179 lines) reveals mostly log files I have recently deleted, a few others, but all in /var/log and /var/tmp. Largest was a 23 mb file.

Comment: I see my swap file appears to be a very large size...probably because I have been running so many intensive programs on this machine.  Is it possible it is hogging disk space?  swapon -s reveals /dev/sda5 , so is that a different partition or does it share space with /dev/sda1?

Comment: I have some times that problem on ssd servers, disk go UP, I check all dirs and dont see nothing, no large, files, no large logs, but if reboot the server I see more free space.

Comment: Skamasle...thanks!  I rebooted, and now have 46% free!  How do I rep you :-)  Still...it might fill up again eventually...still don't know why.

Comment: Nevermind...already back to 80% full. WHat I need is a daily list of new files, or files that have grown in siz.

Comment: Andrew, I did this:  lsof -n | grep -i '(deleted)'  and it shows a lot of files. How do I get rid of them?

Comment: SOLVED: Restarting apache cleared it all out. I had a line for error reporting turned on in one of my big php scripts...and there were tons of warnigs and errors. I was running it about 50,000 times per day...so it added up. Removed error reporting, disk stable.

Answer (score 0):

You do not appear to have a separate /var partition.  I would start looking there for run away logging.